# AS3 Accelerometer for Orientation - side ways only

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, accelerometer

I'm using

```
        var myConst:Number = Math.sin(Math.PI/4);
            if(e.accelerationX > 0 && e.accelerationY > -myConst && e.accelerationY < myConst){
                // fire left
            }
            else if(e.accelerationX < 0 && e.accelerationY > -myConst && e.accelerationY < myConst){
                //fire right
            }   
        }
```

To detect orientation in a mobile device, however this is being fired when the device is tilted forward and back as well as rotated.

How do make it only fire when it's rotated to the side?